# How can I pass Appsync IAM authentication via curl command

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am using Appsync for graphql application and use IAM authentication for some of the mutations. My question is how I can use `curl` command to send a mutation request to Appsync which is using IAM authentication.

I know I can add a header `-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"` if it is using OIDC or API Key. but what header I should use for IAM authentication?

Comment: Use postman and then in the authorization tab use AWS Signature and set the access key and secret. You can then copy the curl command or else create AWS Sig V4 auth header using other mechanism

Comment: postman doesn't work for AWS signature. it still uses old way which is not supported by AWS